# Incorrect access to static class member

Tags: php, static

I have following code

```
class DataMapperFactoryBeta
{
    static private $configClassName = 'ConfigBeta';
    static private $client;
    static private $mapper = [];


    static public function initClient()
    {
        $className = 'Models\\DataMappers\\Clients\\'.self::$configClassName::$db_type;
    }
}
```

The Interpretor throws me a fatal error: 'incorrect access to static class member'. I wish to have the config class name accessed dynamicly, because I will change it in the future and I don't wanna change it in many places in the code, only once, through $configClassName. Is this even possible with statics?

Comment: `$configClassName` is a string. `self::$configClassName::$db_type` means that you are trying to access a static property from a string.

Comment: true, but can't i store the name of a static class, so i can access that static class dynamically?

Comment: You can. If you do it like watcher shown in his answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your line into two, and it should work for you as you expect:

```
$className = 'Models\\DataMappers\\Clients\\' . self::$configClassName;
$className = $className::$db_type;
```

On a side note, I couldn't find in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) whether the scope resolution operator (`::`) is left or right associative. It could be it's trying to interpret the line as follows:

```
('Models\\DataMappers\\Clients\\'.self::($configClassName::$db_type));
```

Without an update from the docs the code is ambiguous as to what exactly *should* be happening the way you have it written.